# Puppet: Notify exec only once for multiple file resource declarations

Tags: puppet

I have a scenario wherein i have 5 template files that needs to be copied to the puppet agent machine. And i want to notify an exec resource if there is a change in any one of the template files. But the exec resource have to be called only once. That is, if there is a change in 2 or more files, then the exec resource have to be called only once. I tried googling but couldn't find a way to achieve the same. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behaviour.
Every resource is only executed once.

For example here:

```
exec { 'foo':
  command     => '/bin/echo x >> /tmp/foo',
  refreshonly => true,
}

file { '/tmp/a':
  ensure => file,
  notify => Exec['foo'],
}

file { '/tmp/b':
  ensure => file,
  notify => Exec['foo'],
}
```

The `exec` will only run once, even if both `/tmp/a` and `/tmp/b` do not exist.

But also note that the exec here will not run at all if both `/tmp/a` and `/tmp/b` *do* exist (due to the `refreshonly => true` parameter).